# Microsoft .NET Core SDK manager

Tags: .net-core

It turned out that i have tens of side by side installed *Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.??? (x64)* visible from Apps & Features windows settings. 
e.g.

```
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.100 (x64)
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.102 (x64)
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.104 (x64)
...
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.509 (x64)
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.511 (x64)
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.101 (x64)
```

Is there some kind of "dotnet core" runtime manager to keep these under control? e.g. like we have Android SDK manager where we can install/uninstall what we need in a batch?

**Note:** My problem is that if there is no such manager, i have to manually go through all uninstalls one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to generate a `globals.json` file in your current working directory, if you use the CLI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x

Comment: Thanks! But this is how to manage the CLI context. I"m interested the managing the available SDKs at an OS level.